# How to setting Windows Command Prompt's environment from other program's output

Tags: windows, batch-file

Also we can setting windows command prompt's environment from file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set command prompt from other program's output:

```
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('anyprog param1 param2') do set PROMPT=%%a
```

To set command prompt from file:

```
set /P PROMPT=< anyfile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo|set /p=set QT_INSTALL_BINS=>%Temp%\_run_temp.bat
qmake -query "QT_INSTALL_BINS">>%Temp%\_run_temp.bat
call %Temp%\_run_temp.bat
del %Temp%\_run_temp.bat
echo %QT_INSTALL_BINS%
```